# Is it allowed to pass a int value inside the feed_dict?

Tags: tensorflow

For every data batch input of data, I also need to provide an int value to the graph. I need to access the value at the run time. Can I do it using the feed_dict?

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeding the data yourself using `feed_dict`, then you can feed another integer. You can feed any node in the graph that is not being fetched, so you could have a `tf.placeholder` node for instance.

If you are using input pipeline with `tf.batch`, then `session.run` calls are issued by queue runners, and you don't have an option to specify a feed dict. In latter case you need to include your integer along with your input data somehow.